# white space under bootstrap carousal on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```css
.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-inner {
        .item {
            transition-property: opacity;
        }
        
        .item,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .active,
        .next.left,
        .prev.right {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .next,
        .prev,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            left: 0;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    .carousel-control {
        z-index: 2;
    }

}





.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-inner {
        .item {
            transition-property: opacity;
        }
        
        .item,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .active,
        .next.left,
        .prev.right {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .next,
        .prev,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            left: 0;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    .carousel-control {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}




html, 
body, 
.carousel, 
.carousel-inner, 
.carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
}

.item:nth-child(2) {

}

.item:nth-child(3) {
    
}


here is the html:
```

```html
  <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item" style="height:100%;">
            
             <h2 style="position:absolute;margin:13.5% 0 0 40%;z-index:3;font-size:250%;color:gold;font-family:oleo;font-style:italic;"
                 id="h2" class="dtext">Specializing in Wood and Salt crafts</h2>
            
            <p class="lead dtext" id="p" style="position:absolute;margin:20.5% 0 0 42%;z-index:3;font-size:170%;color:gold;font-family:variane; width:35%;text-align:centre;font-style:italic;">
            
                Trading in almost all kinds of products but you will love our specially designed wooden goods and salt items
            
            </p>
            
            
            <p class="lead dtext" id="p" style="position:absolute;margin:34.5% 0 0 42%;z-index:3;font-size:170%;color:gold;font-family:variane; width:35%;text-align:centre;font-style:italic;">
            
                It's where most of our love and effort goes in...
            
            </p>
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            <img src="img/pexels-photo-28620.jpg" class="image-responsive" style="position:absolute;z-index:2;overflow-y:hidden;" />
        
            
        
        </div>
        <div class="item"><img class="image-responsive" src="img/salt-lamps-1047941_1920.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img class="image-responsive" src="img/port-1569694_1920.jpg" /></div>
    </div>
    

    <!--       <a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a> -->
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel" data-slide="next" style="margin:22% 4% 0 0;height:6%;border:1px solid grey;width:8%;padding:2.5 0 0 0;" id="a">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

I am creating a website and am stuck at this white space which appears under the bootstrap carousal image only when viewing on mobile phone but not on desktops or large screens.

I have googled but can't find an appropriate answer to this problem would love to have some help...

[image]

here is the css:

```
.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-inner {
        .item {
            transition-property: opacity;
        }

        .item,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .active,
        .next.left,
        .prev.right {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .next,
        .prev,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            left: 0;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    .carousel-control {
        z-index: 2;
    }

}





.carousel-fade {
    .carousel-inner {
        .item {
            transition-property: opacity;
        }

        .item,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        .active,
        .next.left,
        .prev.right {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        .next,
        .prev,
        .active.left,
        .active.right {
            left: 0;
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    .carousel-control {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}




html, 
body, 
.carousel, 
.carousel-inner, 
.carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
}

.item:nth-child(2) {

}

.item:nth-child(3) {

}
```

Comment: provide full code in your question or put on code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

carousel-inner .item is the container of the image. But image will not break its proposition until you force it. Ratio of height/width of image will not exceed to break its pixels. So image will take the maximum width and maximum possible height keeping the height and width ratio same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make it responsive? If you are then I would just recommend the following:

```
.tales {
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 200px !important;
}
```

However, the best way to handle this responsively would be thru the use of media queries like such:

```
/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {}

/* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function and adjust it to fit your size

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = $(window).height();  //getting windows height
    jQuery('#myCarousel').css('height', height - 300 + 'px');   //and setting height of carousel
});
```